# Postmessage strings?

Tags: c#, string, postmessage

I have a script written in Autoit that I am trying to convert over to C# to have more functionality with it down the road. The main functions it ends up having is to send text to a command (In-game text) to a game that I have open. What I am trying to do is get the same kind of functionality of the Send() function in Autoit.

I have been reading and have come to the conclusion that Postmessage and Sendmessage would be the best because they are able to send it to a window that is not currently active. Is there a way to send stings with PostMessage? I attempted to use Sendmessage and while it was sending key presses to the game some of them were not being accepted but post message seems to have them working.

**Question:** Is it possible to send strings and variable with Postmessage()? If so how?

Thanks! I'm still new to C# and trying to make the leap from a way simpler language. (Autoit)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send strings between processes using `PostMessage`.

Because you are trying to send text across a process boundary, that text needs to be marshalled from the sender's process to the receiver's process. That would involve allocating a string on the heap of the receiving  process. Because messages are delivered asynchronously, there would need to be a mechanism for the receiver of the message to free that marshalled string. But no such mechanism exists.

Even for synchronous messages delivered with `SendMessage`, only certain messages perform string marshalling. Only the messages that are defined by the system and designed to carry string payload perform cross-process marshalling. And even then, it's only the messages that are intended to be used cross-process. So you cannot use user-defined messages to send strings cross-process with `SendMessage`.

You will need to find a more capable IPC mechanism. Or send text character by character.

Comment: Well that sucks. Is there really any method to accomplish that? I would be fine with sending a keystroke for each but half of the text is an unknown variable until the program runs and generates the required string. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send keys (which is what I believe Send does in Autoit), you need to send the WM_KEYDOWN message and send the virtual keys as the wParam:

```
const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const int VK_A = 0x41;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

Then to use it, you need the window handle:

```
var windowHandle = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("someprocess")[0].Handle;
PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_A, 0);
```

A list of KeyCodes can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yeah. I have gotten that down and can send individual key presses but part of what I need to send ends up being a variable that I wont know until process run. Was looking for a method of sending something like that. Thanks for the list of keycodes though! I'm sure it will come in handy somewhere.